# Roblox studio error attempt to index nil with getMouse()

Tags: lua, roblox

so, my code is this:

```
while game.Players.LocalPlayer == nil do
    player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    wait(0.1)
end




local mouse = player:GetMouse()


mouse.Button1Up:Connect(addpoints())

function addpoints()
    print("add points")
end
```

and the error is on the line that says local mouse = player:GetMouse() the while loop is to find the local player and not get nil because the script runs when you join the game so if it runs immediately it will get nil. but for some reason it still gets nil for player and then i get the error attempt to index nil with getMouse()

Answer (score 0):

if the script is somewhere in StarterPlayerScripts i dont think you have to wait for player since the script would not work if the "player" is not a thing.
The most likely reason for your problem is because game.Players.LocalPlayer is already a thing so it does NOT return `nil`, so script doesnt even bother to go inside the while loop so you never set the `player` variable.

But if you still want to be sure player is a thing, this should work:

```lua
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
while player == nil do
    print("Player is nil")
    -- you will see this wont print anything since the game.Players.LocalPlayer is not nil
    player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    wait(0.1)
end

local mouse = player:GetMouse()
mouse.Button1Up:Connect(addpoints)
function addpoints()
    print("add points")
end
```

Comment: I tried your example code, i sill got an error but instead of it being where i define mouse it is where i use mouse. the part that says mouse.Button1Up:Connect(addPoints()) the error message is attempt to call a nil value.

Comment: Is it still not working? (I edited the code yesterday) @Killercarrot102

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm like half a year late but I'm new so I need rp.

First thing, like @xlAsdas said, the you dont even need the while loop.

Second thing, you need to define the function first.

Here is a the working code that I tested:

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()

function addpoints()
print("add points")
end

mouse.Button1Up:Connect(addpoints)

Another way is to define the function INSIDE the connect, like this:

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()

mouse.Button1Up:Connect(function()
print("add points")
end)

Also I don't know how to add code properly because I'm new.